# Funny css rendering error in IE background-image has "display: block" in it

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, styles

There is a funny issue with how IE is parsing/rendering my css.  I have the following style defined "background-image: url(/images/leftArrow.png); DISPLAY: block; cursor: pointer;"

but for some reason, IE 7 & 8 are combining background and display to make it one property (see screenshot)

Any ideas?

[image]
<sub>(source: [infinicastonline.com](http://jeremy.infinicastonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/ie-bug.png))</sub>

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the code, instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only displays that way with the [developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en). When you make a simple span with those css attributes, it does actually display like a block element, but my developer toolbar shows the same thing yours does in your screenshot.

It is not the uppercase name (developer toolbar actually makes the display attribute uppercase), nor is the quotes around the url the problem. You can even move `display:block` to the beginning of the styles and it will still show them combined in developer toolbar

Comment: This seems to be it.  There aren't any issues.  I was just wondering what was making it happen.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting some quotes inside the url.

```
url("/images/leftArrow.png");
```

But definitely, more code would be nice.

Comment: added them, and lowercased the display and still displaying the same.

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely a typo somewhere or a forgotten declaration termination or something. If you post the actual code we might be able to provide a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

i think its because you've used uppercase property names. you have the same issue with "POSITION" below. btw how do i get this firebug like addon for ie?

Comment: @Jeremy: Its something elsewhere as ive used jcarousel extensively and never had this problem in IE. Does your HTML validate??? Also in response to a comment attached directly to the question - is this actually causing any issue in your layout or is it simply in your live debug that its an issue? Id be willing to bet its your debug plugin.

Comment: It is an addon from microsoft. You can download it at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Comment: I believe IE8 comes with a version of it as well. To open it in IE8 go to 'Tools -> Developer Tools'